# OpenCV 3.1: CMake error if source or bin path contains "++"

Tags: path, cmake, opencv3.0

If the source or binary path in CMake contain the character sequence "++" (without quotation marks) I get a CMake error when trying to create a project for OpenCV 3.1:

```
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:76 (if):
  if given arguments:

    "G:/Desktop/C++ projects/project" "MATCHES" "^G:/Desktop/C++ projects/sources" "OR"     "G:/Desktop/C++ projects/project" "MATCHES" "^G:/Desktop/C++ projects/project"

  Regular expression "^G:/Desktop/C++ projects/sources" cannot compile
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:437 (ocv_include_directories)
```

Apparently this line inside OpenCVUtils causes the problem:

`if("${__abs_dir}" MATCHES "^${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}" OR "${__abs_dir}" MATCHES "^${OpenCV_BINARY_DIR}")`

I noticed the problem because I have a folder called "C++ Projects" where I keep C++ projects and libraries. Does anyone know, why the sequence causes the problem and if there is a quick way to fix this? I will also report this as a bug in the OpenCV bug tracker.

Comment: Just renamed my `c++` dir to `cpp` to avoid all such situations with CMake in other projects in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` is a special character used in pattern matching ([documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/string.html?highlight=pattern#regex-specification)). The `MATCHES` indicates a pattern matching.

Either the strings have to be escaped first or the real fix would be to test whether `__abs_dir` is the [beginning of the string](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/string.html?highlight=pattern#find) of `OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR`:

```
string(FIND "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}" "${__abs_dir}" strPosSrc)
string(FIND "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}" "${__abs_dir}" strPosBin)
if (strPosSrc EQUALS 0 OR strPosBin EQUALS 0)
```

So basically it is a bug in OpenCV. Ask them to fix it.

**Missing CMake feature**

Overall I think it is a missing CMake feature that it does not provide a method to escape input strings.

There are bugs that could be solved by such a function:
https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15908
https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=10365

Comment: Yes, I know that "+" is used in regular expressions. However, a single + doesn't cause the error, only the double one. Is there a way to automatically escape such characters in a string in cmake?

Comment: Does the substring method really do the same? I think it will return true also if `OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR` is a subdirectory of `__abs_dir`, not only if it is exactly the same directory. Apart from that I suppose your second line above should be `string(FIND "${OpenCV_BINARY_DIR}" "${__abs_dir}" strPosBin)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Oh thanks, I used substring ambiguous, corrected now. I am not aware of a command that espaces your string. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569660/cmake-escaping-symbols-inside-a-variable-in-regular-expressions

Comment: Ok, I fixed the problem for me by replacing the lines 76 and 94 with the code `string(REPLACE "++" "\\+\\+" __abs_dir_escaped ${__abs_dir})`, `string(REPLACE "++" "\\+\\+" OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR_ESCAPED ${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR})`, `string(REPLACE "++" "\\+\\+" OpenCV_BINARY_DIR_ESCAPED ${OpenCV_BINARY_DIR})`, `if("${__abs_dir_escaped}" MATCHES "^${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR_ESCAPED}" OR "${__abs_dir_escaped}" MATCHES "^${OpenCV_BINARY_DIR_ESCAPED}")`

Comment: Should work, but I think my version is more general and will be slightly faster. However, have you reported this issue to OpenCV?

Comment: But with the substring method I'm not sure if it's exactly the same. However, the OpenCV people will have to figure out what works best. The bug report is here: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/6046 You can add your solution if you like.

Comment: Btw. the cmake documentation says that string(find...) also uses "+" as a special character.

Comment: "FIND will return the position where the given substring was found in the supplied string. If the REVERSE flag was used, the command will search for the position of the last occurrence of the specified substring.

The following characters have special meaning in regular expressions: [...]"
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/string.html

Comment: There is a paragraph between the two sentences. The regular expressions are not applied to FIND. Compare the most recent documentation 3.4, which has different order of subsections and does not confuse anymore: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/string.html

Comment: Ok, well that's a weird placement then.